# I want to extract a database from a sever using an url using php code

Tags: php

http://www.amazinglaundryservices.com/hybrid_app/staging_webservices/get_location_area.php

This is my link. I want to fetch the data from this link and display it in a tabular format using a php code.

Comment: Where is your code to achieve this? and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in php

**The file_get_contents() reads a file into a string.**

This function is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. Because it will use memory mapping techniques, if this is supported by the server, to enhance performance.

> **Syntax**  file_get_contents(path,include_path,context,start,max_length)

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("http://www.amazinglaundryservices.com/hybrid_app/staging_webservices/get_location_area.php");
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_R(json_decode($data, true));
    $fileData = json_decode($data, true);
    echo "<table border='1px solid'><tr><td>area_key</td><td>location_area</td><td>sort_key</td></tr>";
    foreach($fileData as $val) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$val['area_key']."</td><td>".$val['location_area']."</td><td>".$val['sort_key']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes @SamuelLiew I know how to answer but here we create rough sketch view for user query ... :) Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code worked perfectly. Thanks for your time. :) @AmanKumar